# Посчитать средний статус среди поставщиков по городам, но отобразить только города, где больше 1 проекта

Tags: mysql, база-данных, запрос, таблицы, подзапрос

Это задание по запросу к базе данных MySQL.

В бд есть таблица `Suppliers` (Поставщики) с полями:

- `SNUM` (вместо ID)
- `SNAME`
- `STATUS`
- `CITY`

Таблица `Jobs` (Проекты) с полями:

- `JNUM`
- `JNAME`
- `CITY`

Таблица `spj`, которая соединяет две эти таблицы, (не знаю, нужна ли она для этого задания) с полями:

- `JNUM`
- `SNUM`.

Нужно посчитать среднее арифметическое статусов поставщиков для каждого города, но отобразить только те города, где больше 1 проекта. Я знаю, как посчитать среднее арифметическое по городам:

```
SELECT Suppliers.City, AVG(Suppliers.STATUS) AS Summ FROM Suppliers
GROUP BY Suppliers.City
```

Не могу понять, как при этом отобразить только те города, где больше одного проекта. Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Ну, видимо, нужно сделать `JOIN` таблицы `Jobs` по полю `CITY` и поставить в конце условие `HAVING COUNT(JNUM) > 1`, остальное всё что нужно у вас уже есть.

Полный запрос не пишу, потому что это всё-таки ваше домашнее задание.

P.S. `Summ` - не очень так название для среднего арифметического. Хотя понятно, что вы это с какого-то примера переписали.

Comment: Спасибо за полезный ответ! У меня получился такой код: `SELECT Suppliers.City, AVG(Suppliers.STATUS) AS Summ FROM Suppliers
JOIN Jobs ON Suppliers.City = Jobs.CITY
GROUP BY Jobs.CITY
HAVING COUNT(JNUM) > 1`
И вроде бы все получилось, но тут я увидела, что в результате посчитано не только среднее арифметическое тех городов, где больше 1 проекта, но и у города, где больше 1 поставщика. Не можете подсказать, что у меня не так?

Comment: Интересный вопрос. Это надо подумать, может тогда нужно вложенный селект сделать. Сейчас не соображу, может завтра